# Infinite or NaN error in java

Tags: java

i'm new in java and i have problem with Bigdecimal.
i received "Infinite or NaN" while converting MS SQL procedure to Java

Sql statement is:

```
ROUND(1-POWer(1 - qx, 0.08333333333333), 19)
FROM planmortalitytable
WHERE age = (FLOOR(@PrevIAgeInsured) + 1)
  AND Plancode = @strPlanCode;
```

I tried:

```
dblProbability_qx = new BigDecimal(
    Math.pow(qx.subtract(new BigDecimal(1)).doubleValue(), 0.08333333333333)
).setScale(19, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

***Note:** `qx` is retrieved from the database*

I don't know what's wrong.

Regards,
Babak

Comment: Looks like just a typo, you have `1-qx` in SQL, but `qx.subtract(new BigDecimal(1))` in Java _(should be `new BigDecimal(1).subtract(qx)`)_

Comment: That should be the answer @phflack

Comment: @sarkasronie [Questions arising from typos are normally just closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319399/closing-questions-with-typos-faster-typo-hammer)

Comment: Nah, sorry @phflack - I didn't mean the "stackoverflow answer". I just meant it like "yeah, that could probably be the problem"